# How can I control my application with built-in voice control?

Tags: ios, voice, voice-control

Let's say I develop audio player for iPod Touch 4/iPhone. Currently it can be controlled with standard panel (double click Home and scroll left).
But how can I control that with built-in voice control (long click on Home)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a VoiceServices framework (more info [here](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2010/02/iphone-voiceservices-looking-under-the-hood.ars)) that may do what you want. Unfortunately, the VoiceServices framework is not part of the public SDK and it can't be used in apps submitted to the store.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I control that with built-in voice control

There's a new **iOS 13** feature called **Voice Control** that may help you to control your application and your device more generally with your voice.

Activate this feature in your device settings `Accessibility` - `Voice Control` as follows:
[image]

Take a look at the `Customize Commands` menu to dive into the vocal commands.

The only thing to do as a developer is eventually to adapt the **`accessibilityUserInputLabels`** properties if you need specific names to be displayed for some items.

The **Voice Control** feature is definitely **THE** built-in tool to reach your purpose.